# Turning date strings into usable date objects in R

Tags: r, posixct, strptime, as.date, posixlt

My strings look like:

`[1] "Sunday, April 10, 2016"     "Saturday, April 16, 2016"`

I would like to apply an algorithm in R so they each read something like this and have a Class POSIXlt or POSIXct:

`[1] "04/10/2016"         "04/16/2016"`

I tried to use `strptime` and `as.Date` functions, but I just cannot find a good way of doing this automatically without first removing the day of the week up front.

Any and all solutions are appreciated! I know many of you are R gurus out there, and I would very much appreciate your help!

Thank you.

Comment: From the `strptime` help: `%A
Full weekday name in the current locale. (Also matches abbreviated name on input.)`. Do you have a specific locale that cause it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all in `help(strptime)`:

```
R> d <- c("Sunday, April 10, 2016", "Saturday, April 16, 2016")
R> as.Date(d, "%A, %B %d, %Y")
[1] "2016-04-10" "2016-04-16"
R>
```

Note that the result of `as.Date()` returns a `Date` object with which you can compute properly: make chanages, add/subtract, compare, convert and format differently for output if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much - this is exactly the solution I was looking for! Much appreciated